# how to get rows from table which are not mentioned in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

i got 2 tables with following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id bigint not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(255) default '',
  primary key(id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_links(
  user_id bigint,
  job_id bigint
);
```

so users are linked to jobs (`jobs` table structure is not needed for this question)

i need to get **all users which are not linked to any job** at one time using one query

for example, if i have tables with such data:

```
users:
id | name
1  | james
2  | fred

user_links:
user_id | job_id
1       | 5
1       | 6
```

then i need result rows like this:

```
id | name
2  | fred
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM users
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id
                    FROM user_links)
```

Answer (score 3):

... assuming there are no NULL user_id in user_links:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_links ON users.id = user_links.user_id
WHERE user_links.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: nice. it this faster than the zerkms' idea?

Comment: @dimaninc: mature DBMS (sql server, postgresql and oracle) would generate the same execution plan. And for `WHERE EXISTS (...)` it would be the same as well. The issue here is that `NOT IN` isn't optimized by B-Tree and in G. Stoynev's answer you anyway are selecting everything from `users`